# SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable PDFKit PDFView AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute

Tags: pdfkit, retain-cycle, uiviewrepresentable

**Edit:**
Created a sample project illustrating the issue:

https://github.com/Harold-D/PDFView_Representable

**Question:**

I'm at a lost, I have this very simple UIViewRepresentable wrapper around PDFView in SwiftUI

```
import PDFKit
import SwiftUI

struct MyPDFView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PDFView
    @Binding var pdf: Data

    func makeUIView(context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyPDFView>) -> UIViewType {
        return PDFView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: UIViewType, context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyPDFView>) {
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: pdf)
    }
}
```

It displays the PDF correctly, but produces about 18 `AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute` messages.

```
@Binding var pdfStruct: PDFStruct
var body: some View {
    MyPDFView(pdf: Binding($pdfStruct.pdf)!)
}
```

```
struct PDFStruct {
    var pdf: Data?
}
```

How can I eliminate the retain cycle?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Im having the same issue

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. But now while typing this reply I wonder if it occurs on a real device as well, only tested it on the simulator.

Comment: I'm experiencing this too, and it does occur on a real device, not just on the simulator.

Comment: Also having this, any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The way I solved it was by removing the line  `pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: pdf)` from the updateUIView function. I think this was causing the issue as its trying to update the document while code is still working with the document. This is how I've now done my PDFKitView

```
    import PDFKit
    import SwiftUI

    struct PDFKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
       typealias UIViewType = PDFView

       let pdfDocument : PDFDocument

       init(showing pdfDoc: PDFDocument){
       self.pdfDocument = pdfDoc
    }

    func makeUIView(context: 
    UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitView>) -> UIViewType {
        let pdfView =  PDFView()
        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    
    }
  }
```

Comment: the spacing is a bit weird in my code block